# Using custom class as a parameter/field in J2EE application

Tags: java, jasper-reports

I am trying to pass the custom object value to Jasper report, I am using compiled jasper i.e `.jasper` file.

Passing the parameter in jrxml

```
<parameter name="STUDENT_ID" class="abc.xyz.Student"/>
```

Trying to access the parameter in jrxml

```
      <textField>
            <reportElement x="156" y="100" width="403" height="20" uuid="20cc6538-41d9-4fe5-ba43-e3152b073e10"/>
            <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[":    "+$P{STUDENT_ID}.getId()]]></textFieldExpression>
      </textField>
```

Structure:

```
jasper/
   temp.jasper
WEB-INF/
   classes/
   lib/
   web.xml
```

Service class

```
Student student = session.get("student")
HashMap<String, Object> map = new HashMap<String, Object>(1);
map.put("STUDENT_ID", student);
print = JasperFillManager.fillReport(ServletActionContext.getServletContext().getRealPath("/jasper/temp.jasper"), map, new JREmptyDataSource());
```

`Student` class will vary student to student, Student class has the fields `id` and `name` with `getters and setters`, but somehow values are not getting rendered on generated PDF file.

How to access the Student object?

Comment: If your `Student` object that you pass by parameter is not `null`, then you might have a template design issue. And without seeing some sample JRXML reproducing the issue, we can't tell what's wrong.

Comment: I think I am missing classpath or something else.

Answer (score 0):

At first view I can't see nothing wrong with your code, but if you are passing an empty data source, be sure to not place the field you want on Datails band. Without data source, this band is not rendered. Test it putting the field on Title band, for example.

Comment: I have the field in detail band. Detail band is getting rendered I can see the static fields.